# Galaxy book audio in/out port treats microphone jack as headphones

Tags: windows, laptop, audio

I have a samsung galaxy book running Windows 11 with a combination 3.5mm audio port, and a Behringer XM8500 microphone with a TRS jack.
If I plug this mic into the laptop's audio port, (via a 6.35mm to 3.5mm adapter) it thinks I've plugged headphones into it.

Presumably this is because the mic jack is TRS and not TRRS?
Is it possible to convert a TRS jack into a TRRS jack with some kind of adapter?
The laptop has 2 usb-c ports and a thunderbolt port.
Is there any way of telling windows that the jack is audio input?
Or do I need some kind of hub or docking station to resolve this?

Comment: Thank you. Yes that is pretty much the same question. I tried the suggested solution but it didn't work. I'll follow that question for further advice.